# How to remove Magento's password matching in account registration form?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, forms, form-validation, password

I am creating a custom user registration page for which I copied registration.phtml to another location and I am working with it.

And for that page I don't want the user to be enforced to enter the password twice.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Magento has perform server side validation for customer registration, so conformation password is must.***

Copy this file to your theme with correct folder structure

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
```

Then make conformation password field as hidden

```
<input type="hidden" name="confirmation" title="<?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?>" id="confirmation" />
```

Then write a script to copy the password field to confirmation field.

```
jQuery("#password").change(function(){
   jQuery("#confirmation").val(jQuery("#password").val()) 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It turned out the jQuery part could simply be added in the end of the .phtml itself.